# Product of nonsingular matrices

Tags: matrices

I have read that the product of two nonsingular matrices is nonsingular.
So if $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular, then so is $AB$.

But what if we have $AC$ is nonsingular. Is there a rule in factorisation such that if we have a nonsingular matrix $AC$, then both $A$ and $C$ have to be nonsingular?

From my understanding you can have an $n \times n$ nonsingular matrix $A$ and a $n \times n$ nonsingular matrix $D$. So the multiplication would work, but because we have a nonsingular $\times$ singular, do we know what the result would be in terms of invertibility?

All I know is that a nonsingular $\times$ nonsingular $=$ nonsingular

Comment: But what if all I have is $AC$ is nonsingular and I know that $A$ is nonsingular. Is there any way to draw conclusions about $C$ without knowing any entries of the matrices, ie, cannot use det(C).

Comment: oopps, sorry, there is one more detailed I missed. $ACx=0$ homogenous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix **R** is *singular* if $\det$(**R**)=$0$.

A matrix **Q** is *invertible* if $\det$(**Q**)$\neq0$.

We also have that det (**S**) x det(**T**) = det(**ST**).

Therefore, if both **S** and **T** have nonzero determinants, so does **ST** and therefore is invertible.

Comment: Oh yes, I see @SakethMalyala...

Answer (score 1):

If $AB$ is non-singular, then there exists $C$ such that $(AB)C=I$

This implies that $A(BC)=I$, which means that $A$ is invertible and it's inverse is $BC$.

Same works for $B$.